# SQL - Query relating 3 different tables and a weak entity

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, join

I'm doing a database on Oracle SQL Developer as part of an assignment and I'm having some trouble doing a query in which I need to list all the sensors installed for a given type of company in charge of them.

The tables I use for this are the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Company
  (
    IDempresa       INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    Nome            VARCHAR2 (64) ,
    Localizacao     VARCHAR2 (64) ,
    TipoEmpresa_IDE INTEGER NOT NULL
  ) ;
ALTER TABLE Company ADD CONSTRAINT Company_PK PRIMARY KEY ( IDempresa ) ;

CREATE TABLE Sensor
  (
    ID_sensor      INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    Cost          NUMBER ,
    TipoSensor_IDS INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    Precisao FLOAT ,
    Infra_IDinf INTEGER NOT NULL
  ) ;
ALTER TABLE Sensor ADD CONSTRAINT Sensor_PK PRIMARY KEY ( ID_sensor ) ;

CREATE TABLE TypeCompany
  (
    IDE         INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    Name        VARCHAR2 (64) ,
    AreaService VARCHAR2 (64)
  ) ;
ALTER TABLE TypeCompany ADD CONSTRAINT TypeCompany_PK PRIMARY KEY ( IDE ) ;
```

Essentially what I need is to get a list of all the sensors given an area of service. The problem is the area of service belongs to the type of company table, which originates a number of companies (1 to n relation) which are then tied to the sensors themselves in an m to n relation.

So my problem is that I can do selects between two tables with a natrual join, but now I'm stuck as I don't know if I have to use local variables to store the id's as I get them (if that makes any sense) to relate the 4 tables I need (type of company, company, the weak entity created from company to sensor and sensor, the final one being the list I need to make) or if there is another way.

Edit:

Here is a print of the model relating all the tables: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgKup.jpg

I'll try and explain what I need again: given the 'AreaService' parameter from the table TypeCompany I need to list all the information from the table Sensor. I don't however know how to save all the id's that I need to get there. I've read about joins but I don't know how to actually use them nor if they solve my problem. Sorry if it is a stupid question.

Comment: Why did you not include the structure for the company table? It would be a lot easier to help you write your query if you would supply an example dataset and the predicted outcome of your query regarding that dataset.

Comment: @Yaron Idan I'm sorry, my tables are created with portuguese names (since I'm portuguese). I edited the names of the tables to their equivalent names in english.

Comment: As I said, an example dataset and query outcome would help a lot in this case. I don't really see by which column is the sensor table connected to any of the other two tables.

Comment: Oh ok, I am gonna take a print screen of my model and I will edit the OP with it in a minute, sorry, like I said it's the first time im using this programming language and I can't really express myself well.

Comment: @YaronIdan I've added the print screen to the original post. Here it is anyway: http://imgur.com/cWJQQEq

Comment: Thanks for the print screen, but it still doesn't answer my question, what is the connecting column between the sensor table and the rest of the tables? 
If there is no column connecting this table to the other two there is no way to join them. I understand that the typeCompany and company tables are connected by the IDE and TipoEmprese_IDE respectively. What is the equivalent example regarding the sensor table and one of the two other tables?

Comment: Well the sensor table is connected to the company table in an m to n relation. So basically a weak entity is created between these two tables (that relation 11 that shows up there in the print screen) and thats what's connecting them. When I install a sensor in a point of the city, that sensor needs to be connected to a company that will act on it. So the weak entity that pops up is what represents that connection.

Comment: FYI: SQLfiddle is a great tool for defining database structures and DML. Oracle is supported. It helps us to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm using the data modeler because it's what my teachers gave us to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking into account all of the details you've supplied, and treating the weak entity in your ERD as an additional table (since I don't know any other way to implement this kind of object in Oracle), this query should supply you with what you need -

```
SELECT *
FROM sensor s INNER JOIN Relation_11 r ON s.ID_sensor = r.sensor_ID_sensor
INNER JOIN Company c ON r.Empresa_IDEmpresa = c.IDempresa
WHERE c.IDempresa in (SELECT IDempresa
                      FROM Company c INNER JOIN TypeCompany tc ON c.TipoEmpresa_IDE = tc.IDE
                      WHERE tc.AreaService = <AreaServiceVar>)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for going through all of this and helping, it works!
Could you just explain to me what those inner joins do and do you use "on" on those but the "in" on the where part?

Comment: The in simply checks if the company id of the outside query exists in the company id returned from the inner query. If you found my answer helpful please mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what would the difference between the "in" and a "=" be? 
Also in the end you do a select to get the id that is given by the user input. Is that the usual way to do that in sql? Because I'm used to working with other programming languages my first thought would be to store the id in a local variable and access the table with that variable. I suppose thats not how you do things in sql?

Comment: 1. In is the same as = only it allows you to equate multiple values. = will fail if the subquery returns more than one value.

Comment: Wheb writing SQL queries and when accessing the datavase in general the best practice is to minimize the amount of db access. Your technic would work as well but will not perfoem as well.